# Does $(\sim {[p \Rightarrow (\sim q)] \vee (r \Leftrightarrow s)}) \wedge (r \vee \sim q)$ translate to $NKKNCpNqErsKrqRq$ in Polish Notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In translating $$(\sim {[p \Rightarrow (\sim q)] \vee (r \Leftrightarrow s)}) \wedge (r \vee \sim q)$$

to Polish notation, I got $$NKKNCpNqErsKrq$$

If anyone could give me clarification if this answer is correct or not, I would appreciate it.

Comment: This isn't **reverse** Polish notation. It's Polish notation, but not for the intended formula. To begin with, the given formula has two occurrences of $\lor$, but there's no A in the Polish version.

Comment: Your Polish notation has negation as its main connective; the given formula has conjunction as its main connective.

Answer (score 1):

Translate $NKKNCpNqErsKrq$ back to the usual notation.

- $Krq$ is $r\land q$.
- $Ers$ is $r\leftrightarrow s$.
- $Nq$ is $\neg q$.
- $CpNq$ is $p\to\neg q$.
- $NCpNq$ is $\neg(p\to\neg q)$.
- $KNCpNqErs$ is $\neg(p\to\neg q)\land(r\leftrightarrow s)$.
- $KKNCpNqErsKrq$ is $\big(\neg(p\to\neg q)\land(r\leftrightarrow s)\big)\land(r\land q)$.
- $NKKNCpNqErsKrq$ is $$\neg\left[\big(\neg(p\to\neg q)\land(r\leftrightarrow s)\big)\land(r\land q)\right]\,.$$

As you can check by making a truth table, this is not equivalent to the original expression

$$\left(\neg\left\{\big[p\to(\neg q)\big]\lor(r\leftrightarrow s)\right\}\right)\land(r\lor\neg q)\,.\tag{1}$$

If you have $A$ for disjunction, you can convert $(1)$ as follows:

- $r\lor\neg q$ is $ArNq$.
- The expression inside the curly braces is $ACpNqErs$.
- Negating it yields $NACpNqErs$.
- And the final result is $KNACpNqErsKrq$.

If you don’t have $A$ available, you’ll have to use DeMorgan’s laws to convert $x\lor y$ to $\neg(\neg x\land\neg y)$ and then do the conversion to Polish notation.